# How can I change the color of an adforn ornament?

Tags: color, ornamental-fonts

How can I change the color of an `adforn` ornament ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adforn}
\begin{document}
    \adforn{21}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`adforn` provides its ornaments as a font, so you can change the colors like with any other font. See the `xcolor` documentation for the various ways of using and defining colors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{blue}{\adforn{21}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Doncherry, a very compact solution, I am very thankful ! I would accept both answers (yours and the Bernard's one) if possible !

Answer (score 5):

Here are two ways.

*Unrelated* : unless your distribution is quite old, loading `inputenc` is not necessary any more: `utf8` is what latex expects by default.

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{adforn}
        \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

        \begin{document}

         \centering {\color{VioletRed}\adforn{21}}\qquad \textcolor{DarkSeaGreen}{\adforn{21}}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bernard !!! A very nice solution!! I would accept both answers!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can  help.